# TinyMCE plugin custom tags in Django

Tags: django, tinymce

I am building a custom image insert plugin for TinyMCE. The idea is that each article already has a relationship with a collection of images through an ArticleImage model which allows the user to provide an article-specific caption. The TinyMCE will then insert a custom tag (something like `<myapp:image image-id="9389" caption="Caption override">`) which is rendered as a preview of the image and caption in the editor, and rendered into `<figure><img src="images/9389.jpg" /><figcaption>Caption override (Photo: photographer)</figcaption></figure>`. This could equally be something like `<myapp:poll>` or `<myapp:video>`.

My question is: what is the best way (and where is the best place) to parse this 'dummy tag' into its rendered HTML in the Django view?

Or is there another, better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the best place to render custom markup, is in the template via a templatefilter.

I would risk myself to say that using a templatefilter to render custom markup is the "djangoish" way, since that's the way to go with [django.contrib.markup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/).

Storing the custom tag in the model is a good idea, because then you can change the template filter implementation, which would be impossible if the custom tag is processed before storage.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I did this with a templatefilter containing some BeautifulSoup processing, which works perfectly and also ensures the result is valid and well-formed HTML.